# If else statement not working in custom python function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Below is a minimum reproducible example of what I'm trying to achieve with my custom function. The function works if I remove the if statement and second argument. I know the error is derived from the if statement, but I can't seem to figure out what the solution is.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"odds":[100, -200, -400], "favorite":[0, 1, 1]})

def odd_bin_group_fn(odds, favorite):
    if (odds <= -200 and favorite == 1):
        return('large_favorite')
    else:
        return('other')

df['odd_bin'] = odd_bin_group_fn(df["odds"], df["favorite"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply function on rows, you can use `apply()` with `axis=1`.

```py
df['odd_bin'] = df.apply(lambda row: odd_bin_group_fn(row["odds"], row["favorite"]), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   odds  favorite         odd_bin
0   100         0           other
1  -200         1  large_favorite
2  -400         1  large_favorite
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use anonymous function and `apply()` method:

```
df['odd_bin']=df.apply(lambda x:'large_favorite' if (x['odds']<=-200) & (x['favorite']==1) else 'other',1)
```

**OR**

You can also use numpy's `where()` method:

```
df['odd_bin']=np.where((df['odds']<=-200) & (df['favorite']==1),'large_favorite','other')
```

Comment: Assigned corect columns names.

Comment: I think best answer here - using `np.where`